# The difference between environments in definition time and environments in application time

Tags: sml, environment, ml

I have this code in Standard ML and I want to know what environments and what bindings are created at definition and at application time, and what's the difference between the both.

```
fun boo boo = 
  let
    type boo = int
    val boo : boo = boo
    val boo : { boo : boo } = { boo = boo }
  in
    # boo boo
  end
```

I searched but could not come with an accurate answer,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Homework question?

Comment: Yes, this is part of a homework

Answer (score 0):

I'm still somewhat new to SML, but I think I've got this:

```
fun boo boo (* 1 *) = 
let
    type boo (* 2 *) = int
    val boo (* 3 *) : boo = boo (* 1 *)
    val boo (* 4 *) : { boo (* 5 *) : boo } = { boo = boo } (* 6 *)
in
    # boo boo (* 7 *)
end
```

I labeled each *boo* to keep track of them. They are:

1. A free parameter (to the function 'boo') of type int
2. A type, aliased to type int
3. A new value of type boo (int) which is bound to the parameter passed to the function
4. A record value...
5. with field 'boo' of type boo (int)...
6. that's assigned the "new" boo value from (3)
7. projection of field 'boo' from record 'boo' (has type 'boo' (int))

The overall function has type : `int -> int`